# Overriding knockout binding: cannot apply bindings multiple times error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In **knockout** I want to override default `foreach` binding:

```
var foreachInit = ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init = function () {
    foreachInit.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

But even this simple snippet triggers an error:

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

See console at fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/wxf51s5L/10/

Do you know, why this is happening?

Comment: fun story: after 3 years I was looking similar solution, found this. Decided to answer and then I looked that the question was asked by me :-D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are overthinking stuff here. Create a viewModel constructor, initialize and pass the data you want then store it in an observableArray.

```js
var ViewModel = function(r) {
  // if r exists place it in the observable otherwise it's an empty array
  this.items = ko.observableArray(r || []);
};

var model = new ViewModel([1, 2]);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p data-bind="foreach: items">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your HTML, you have another text-binding, remove that span and your problem is solved.
Or you should tell Knockout that you will control descendant bindings yourself.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an error, you shloud return `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` from `init`, so:

```
var foreachInit = ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init = function () {
    foreachInit.apply(this, arguments);

    return {
        controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
};

ko.applyBindings({
    items: ['A', 'B'],
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/6sar9ftv/3/